# Laravel orWhere not working with hasMany

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have following code:

```
class Ingredient extends Eloquent
{
    public function units()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('IngredientUnit')
                    ->orWhere('ingredient_id', '=', -1);
    }
}
```

I would expect query like:

```
select * from `ingredient_units` where `ingredient_id` = '-1' OR `ingredient_units`.`ingredient_id` in (...)
```

instead I get:

```
select * from `ingredient_units` where `ingredient_id` = '-1' and `ingredient_units`.`ingredient_id` in (...)
```

Why it use AND operator instead OR, when I used orWhere()?

**Update 1:**

And second question is how can I get a query which I was expected?

**Update 2:**

I want to use eagerloading for that

Comment: Could you update the question with your models/relationships to help understand how they are related?

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch a collection of objects through a relation on a model, the relation constraint is always included, hence the **AND**. And it makes perfect sense, otherwise you could get $model->units objects that are not related to **$model**.

I can see what you're trying to achieve here - fetch units related to that **$model** together with units not related to any models. You can achieve it by adding the following method to your model:

```
public function getAllUnits() {
  $genericUnits = IngredientUnit::whereIngredientId(-1);
  return $this->units()->union($genericUnits)->get();
}
```

OR

```
public function getAllUnits() {
  return IngredientUnit::whereIn('ingredient_id', [$this->id, -1])->get();
}
```

The only issue here is that it won't be used by eager loading logic but would result in separate query for every model for which you want to return units. But if you always fetch that for a single model anyway, it won't be a problem.

**One suggestion**: store **NULL** in ingredient_id instead of -1. This way you'll be able to make use of **foreign key constraints**.

Comment: So you are saying it is impossible to do what I want? Are you sure?

Comment: Ok thanks for answer, I updated question again because eager loading is condition here

Comment: It won't work with eager loading as it is implemented in Eloquent. The way eager loading works is that first it fetches all Ingredients, then fetches all Units where ingredient_id in ids of all fetched ingredients, then maps those units to fetched Ingredients using ingredient ID. So it won't work as there is no ingredient with id=-1. What you can do is do the standard eager loading and then fetch the not-linked units in separate query.